# Why do atoms become unstable on higher energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics

In spectroscopy, atoms absorp light of specific wavelenghts that move the electrons to higher energy levels.

The atom becomes unstable at some point and re-emits these wavelenghts to get to its initial energy level.

Why is more energy unstable?

Comment: In general, all systems tend to reach the minimum possible energy. If you leave a stone in the air, it will fall down, because the ground has less potential energy. Everything seeks for the minimum energy

Comment: The more energy is pumped into a system, the more ways it can decays: so it will decay. For particular systems it may be not true ( see rubid lasers). In such cases you usually end with metastable states where various decays channels may be limited ( by conservation principles, or by thickness of decay channels) and which can live much longer than ordinary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entropy can be understood as a ratio of number of microstates and macrostates, entropy increase in this picture looks like a shift toward macrostates that encode a wider set of microstates

As the amount of total energy above base increases, loosely speaking there are more available microstates that can be described in the macro picture as being spread out in many energy pools, than the microstates that can be described with most of the energy in a reduced number of pools. Hence statistically, the system naturally prefers to evolve toward those states where energy is spread out.